# Pip3 python3 egg_info error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I was trying to install some packages with Pip3 on the Python3 setup.
However I ended up getting several errors which I've never seen before.

The errors I am getting are :

```
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_omega/IMDbPY
Storing debug log for failure in /home/omega/.pip/pip.log
```

I saw some people suggested updating so I did and got this :

```
omega@Omega-System:~$ pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
Downloading/unpacking setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=fc7acea179a69c7d9bf8b854fe44b029
Downloading setuptools-14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (501kB): 501kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 11.3.1
Uninstalling setuptools:
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 522, in move os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/easy_install' -> '/tmp/pip-h2lg1ase-uninstall/usr/local/bin/easy_install'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1431, in install
requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
      paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
      renames(path, new_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
      shutil.move(old, new)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 535, in move os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/easy_install'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/omega/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sudo pip3 args`.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/easy_install'
```

Such errors occur when you're running your commands as not privileged user. `/usr/local/bin` *does not* belong to you. It may belong to *root user*.

Comment: Thanks that worked for the upgrade but the : 
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/IMDbPY
Storing debug log for failure in /home/omega/.pip/pip.log

Error persists

Comment: @MeghdeepRay, what does the log say?